# how to combine primary and secondary id into single column in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to update mno column with PID and SID into single column
If both ids are available PID should  be firstly update.

```
 PID    SID
 111    T111
 112    
        T113
```

Expected result :

```
PID  SID    Mno
111  T111   111
112         112
     T113   T113
```

Comment: Can your post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via an `ifelse()` (assuming one of the values is always present, otherwise you need to build in a backup value):

```
df$Mno <- ifelse(!is.na(df$PID), df$PID, df$SID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `dplyr::coalesce` to achieve that task. It takes several variables and returns the first value that is not missing. To combine multiple variables into one new variable you would have to adjust the classes. And if your missing values are just blank (in case you have character variables), you would have to recode these values first.

Anyways ... here is an example that should work

```
dplyr::tibble(PID=c(111,112,NA),
              SID=c("T111",NA,"T113")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Mno=dplyr::coalesce(as.character(PID),
                                      SID))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    PID SID   Mno  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1   111 T111  111  
2   112 NA    112  
3    NA T113  T113
```